# Replace attribute value in an HTML string using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a filter hook that passes a string of HTML. An example string might be:

```
'<input type="text" value="4893" />'
```

The string is passed to the filter hook:

```
add_filter( 'html_filter', 'my_html_filter', 10, 1 );
function my_html_filter( $html ) {

    $html =     <--- REPLACE VALUE ATTRIBUTE HERE

    return $html;
}
```

What I need to do inside of `my_html_filter()` is replace the value of `value=""` and I'm not sure how to isolate this in `$html`. As a random example, say `$html` is passed as:

```
'<input type="text" value="345" />'
```

and I need to change it to:

```
'<input type="text" value="14972" />'
```

How would I do this? A combination of str_replace and a regex expression?

Comment: This will probably work, however using regex on html is never a very good idea. There might be some other hook that just replaces the value only, can you please share what value we are talking about?

Comment: https://eval.in/752568

Comment: Were either of the answers helpful? If so, please upvote and mark one as accepted, or provide feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use an HTML parser to parse HTML!

```
$html = '<input type="text" value="4893" />';
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('input');
$node = $nodes[0];
$node->setAttribute('value', 'foo');
echo $dom->saveHTML($node);
```

Result:

```
<input type="text" value="foo">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'html_filter', 'my_html_filter', 10, 1 );
function my_html_filter( $html ) {

    // assuming you have a way to know the new value you want
    // i used an example value, probably you have to construct 
    // the following string
    $new_value = 'value="65432"';

    $html = preg_replace('/value="[0-9]+"/', $new_value, $html);

    return $html;
}
```